# Finding sum of complex exponentials

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, summation

I'm having trouble finding information on google proving the following result
$$ \left|\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\omega ^{\frac{1}{2}k(k-1)}\right|^2=\begin{cases}
4, \quad \text{if }d\text{ is even},\\
d, \quad \text{if }d \text{ is odd},
\end{cases}$$
where $\omega =e^{2\pi i /d}$ and $d=2,3,4,...$

Could anyone point me in a direction?

Comment: You should look for quadratic Gauss sum, i.e. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20quadratic%20Gauss,a%20more%20general%20Gauss%20sum.